# Adjust kepler map size in dual mode in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, kepler.gl

I want to use kepler map in dual mode (in jupyter), to have 2 visualizations on the same map, on the left is one layer, on the right is another. In normal mode the map looks fine, but in dual it shrinks, see screenshots, first in normal mode, than in dual
[image: Normal mode]

[image: Dual mode]

I played with `height` and `width` of the `KeplerGL`, but it didn't help. I also added

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.output_result { max-width:100% !important; }</style>"))
```

into jupyter cell, but nothing has changed. Please help! I like kepler and if I could solve this thing, it would be just perfect

Answer (score 0):

weird, but I just zoomed with ctrl+mouse wheel and it worked:)